# CORS Axios Redmine

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cors, axios, redmine

I'm using Axios to connect to the Redmine API(bitnami stack for Windows), I configured the http.conf file in Apache adding these lines:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

But I always had the following error:

> Failed to load http://localhost/redmine/projects.json?key=0fxxxxxxxxxx: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404.

My headers : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TldaO.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you got problem yet or not but i solved the issue just by using proxy in my code. instead of that server i used localhost for calling my api and localhost is a proxy for my domain.com.

```
 devServer:
```

{ 
    port: 80,
    proxy: {
          // proxy all requests starting with /api to jsonplaceholder
          '/api': {
            target: 'http://sub.domain.com/',
            changeOrigin: true,
            pathRewrite: {
              '^/api': ''
            }
          }
        }
  },